# Trigger Node stdin data event every time a key is pressed?

Tags: node.js, events, stdin

I am aware this is possible with readline, but I'd like to do it natively to understand how readline does it.

Currently when I do `process.stdin.on('data')` it runs the callback every time I press enter. I'd like to set this up so it runs every time I press any key. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on('data' ---- or ----'readable', () => {
   const key = process.stdin.read();
  .....
}
```